# Can I centralize mapping which I want to ignore in AutoMapper?

Tags: c#, automapper

I have classes which have the usual `CreatedDate`, `CreatedById`, `EditedDate`, `EditedById` and etc. fields on which I ignore when mapping from Domain models -> Entity models (they are populated later by the database).

My mappings are now littered with mapping ignore looking a bit like

```
CreateMap<UpdateProvider, ProviderInstance>()
            .ForMember(e => e.Id, opt => opt.Ignore())
            .ForMember(e => e.CreatedDate, opt => opt.Ignore())
            .ForMember(e => e.CreatedById, opt => opt.Ignore())
            .ForMember(e => e.EditedDate, opt => opt.Ignore())
            .ForMember(e => e.EditedById, opt => opt.Ignore())
            .ForMember(e => e.ArchivedDate, opt => opt.Ignore())
            .ForMember(e => e.ArchivedById, opt => opt.Ignore());
```

Can I centralize this in a single method to adhere to the DRY principle. If it helps each of these fields have interfaces called  `IIdentifiable`, `ICreateable`, `IEditable`, `IArchiveable`.

I was hoping to just create an extension method of something like `.IgnoreDbGeneratedFields<TDestination>()`

Comment: You want `AddGlobalIgnore`.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu I have just tried the `AddGobalIgnore` but that will also ignore when mapping back from an entity -> domain. I kinda want to only use it when mapping from domain -> entity

Comment: You can try `ShouldMapProperty`.

Answer (score 2):

An extension method along the following lines should work:

```
    public static IMappingExpression<T1, T2> IgnoreDbGeneratedFields<T1, T2>(this IMappingExpression<T1, T2> e)
    where T2 : IIdentifiable, ICreateable, IEditable, IArchiveable
{
    return e
        .ForMember(x => x.Id, opt => opt.Ignore())
        .ForMember(x => x.CreatedDate, opt => opt.Ignore())
        .ForMember(x => x.CreatedById, opt => opt.Ignore())
        .ForMember(x => x.EditedDate, opt => opt.Ignore())
        .ForMember(x => x.EditedById, opt => opt.Ignore())
        .ForMember(x => x.ArchivedDate, opt => opt.Ignore())
        .ForMember(x => x.ArchivedById, opt => opt.Ignore());
}
```

Comment: Jonas exactly what I was looking for. I've updated it to be a full example